# S Corp Options Exercise Tax Benefits

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, employee-stock-options, s-corporation

I have options to purchase stock in a S Corp. Is there any tax advantage to exercising those options at least one year prior to a sale of the company for capital gains tax purposes or does concept not apply to the sale of a private company?

Comment: May be relevant: If the company is sold, would you retain your shares or would the buyer also buy up all existing shares?

Comment: For the question my assumption was the the buyer would buy up all existing shares

Comment: OK, just making sure. (Because you might not owe any capital gains tax otherwise at the time of sale.)